# Split a packet in XDP eBPF

Tags: linux-kernel, xdp-bpf

Is it possible to generate several packets out of one incoming packet in XDP eBPF? Or probably there are other kernel based solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, XDP programs are as of now, one packet in, one packet out (or drop). At the TC layer you do have access to the [`bpf_clone_redirect`](https://github.com/libbpf/libbpf/blob/d9d17f6d71b931769cb814ba9f574cb15b30fc33/src/bpf_helper_defs.h#L355) helper function which as the name suggest can send a close of the current packet to a given network interface, after which you can modify the current packet.

Another common technique to called "port mirroring" typically used for monitoring traffic for a number of purposes. Which can also be setup in plain TC without eBPF:

- https://medium.com/swlh/traffic-mirroring-with-linux-tc-df4d36116119
- https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_and_managing_networking/assembly_port-mirroring_configuring-and-managing-networking

Comment: Nice! Looks like port mirroring with some iptables rewriting solves my problem

Comment: Technically, you could use `bpf_clone_redirect` to send a clone of the packet to the same or another interface and modify it a second time.